# How do I check the value of a variable constantly?

Tags: ios, swift

**Objective**

I need to constantly check the value of a `Bool` variable until its value is `true`.

**Code**

I tried including a `do-while` loop in an animation into the code of a function that will be called in the `viewDidAppear` method at runtime. This works fine but it's not an efficient solution.

```
var myVariable: Bool = false
UIView.animateWithDuration(100, animations: {
        do {
            println(myVariable)
        } while variable == false
})
```

I also considered to use the `didSet` property, like so:

```
    var myVariable: Bool = false {
       didSet {
         if myVariable {
           println("Mission completed! The variable is true")
         } else {
           println("Keep checking...")
         }
       }
    }
```

**Question**

How do I check the value of a `Bool` variable constantly?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Do you recommend using the `didSet` property?

Comment: Yes. Why didn't that work for you (or haven't you tried it yet)?

Comment: What will change the value of the variable? Why don't you just have that code trigger whatever it is you want to happen once the value has changed to true?

Comment: I am trying to use the `didSet` property right now. Thanks @rdelmar! @Abhi It's because I am using a feature that I can't control directly (face detection in a live video). Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `addObserver` method, observe for the changes to the value of your variable

Comment: The new value is passed in to willSet, so you probably want to use that rather than didSet.

Comment: @rdelmar It worked fine! Please feel free to add your comments in an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a property observer to your property.

```
var myVariable: Bool = false {
        willSet{
            if newValue == true {
                println("the Bool is now true")
            }
        }
    }
```