# Swift - How to check if value changed

Tags: swift, onchange

As an example, if I had this:

```
var myDate = Date()
```

How would I do:

```
if ( myDate got changed ) { do something }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690426/how-do-i-check-the-value-of-a-variable-constantly/29690862#29690862 ?

Comment: Please read the section about [Property Observers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID262) in the Language Guide

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check the value of a variable constantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690426/how-do-i-check-the-value-of-a-variable-constantly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mean `myDate got changed` you mean when it gets a new affectation ?

Like: `myDate = someFunctionThatReturnADate()`? if so, you can use `didSet`

Something like:

```
var myDate = Date() {
    didSet {
        doSomething()
    }
}
```